# count columns value

Tags: sql, select, count, group-by

Table Name : user_test_details

[image]

I want result as per below,

```
question_id   option_a   option_b   option_c   option_d   option_e
1             0          1          0          0          1
2             2          0          0          0          0
3             0          0          1          0          1
4             0          0          2          0          0
```

I want count of, how many times option_a is repeating in question_id 1, if not then 0, if yes then as per count. Same as other options (option_b, option_c, option_d, option_e). More declaration, Here question_id 4,  option_c is repeating 2 times so, in result, question_id 4, option_c value is 2.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    question_id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN option_a = 'option_a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS option_a,
    SUM(CASE WHEN option_b = 'option_b' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS option_b,
    SUM(CASE WHEN option_c = 'option_c' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS option_c,
    SUM(CASE WHEN option_d = 'option_d' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS option_d,
    SUM(CASE WHEN option_e = 'option_e' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS option_e,
FROM user_test_details
GROUP BY question_id
```

Comment: Thanks you save my time

Answer (score 0):

```
select question_id,count(option_a) as option_a,count(option_b) as option_b,count(option_c) as option_c,count(option_d) as 
option_d,count(option_e) option_e from user_test_details group by question_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT question_id, 
    COALESCE(optA.option_a,0) as option_a, 
    COALESCE(optB.option_b,0) as option_b 
FROM user_test_details
LEFT JOIN 
    (
    SELECT question_id, count(option_a) as option_a FROM user_test_details 
    WHERE
    option_a is not null or option_a <> '' group by option_a) 
AS optA
ON user_test_details.question_id = optA.question_id

LEFT JOIN 
    (
    SELECT question_id, count(option_b) as option_b FROM user_test_details 
    WHERE
    option_b is not null or option_b <> '' group by option_b) 
AS optB
ON user_test_details.question_id = optB.question_id
```

And yes I know it looks dirty.